# how to change the image url when i paste the link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I work in javascript basically I want to show the image when the user pick the image from the device the image must change the code that I use in the javascript file is

```
function changeProfile(){

    var location = document.getElementById("profileLocation");
    alert(location.value);
    var image = document.getElementById("profileAAImage");
    image.src(location.value);
}
```

and the code that I wrote in html file is

```
<div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3 form-group" style="padding-left: 7%;">
                                    <img  id="profileImage" style="border-radius: 200px;" src="images/interne/areab%20suhaib.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" width="100" height="100" >
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-9 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0" style="padding-top: 5%;">
                                    <input  type="file" name="file"  class="form-control" id="profileLocation" onclick="changeProfile()" onkeyup="changeProfile()" placeholder="select profile image"
                                            required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

what I do to do the required task.

Comment: what do you mean by `change the code` can you explain it

Comment: You cannot give image source as file location in user's device. First you need to upload it to your server and then update the image src with server location.

Answer (score 0):

Change `location.value` to `location.files[0]` to get the selected file.

```js
function changeProfile() {
  var location = document.getElementById("profileLocation");
  var image = document.getElementById("profileImage");
  image.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(location.files[0]);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 form-group" style="padding-left: 7%;">
    <img id="profileImage" style="border-radius: 200px;" src="images/interne/areab%20suhaib.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" width="100" height="100">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0" style="padding-top: 5%;">
    <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" id="profileLocation" onchange="changeProfile()" placeholder="select profile image" required>
  </div>
</div>
```